# I want to display nothing when Search input is empty

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-hooks

I am actually using a search function to search in a list (data), the thing is it's showing all the information in the list by default.
How can I hide all the list ? And show it (the results) only once the user typed something in the search input.

Thanks in advance,

Code that I am using :

```
 const [search, setNewSearch] = useState("");

    const handleSearchChange = (e) => {
    setNewSearch(e.target.value);
    };

    const filtered = !search
        ? data
        : data.filter((item) =>
            item.titre.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase())
        
        );
```

return view :

```
 <TextInput style={styles.search}
                    value={search} 
                    onChange={handleSearchChange}
                    ></TextInput>
                    <Text style={styles.text}>Résultat rapide :</Text>
                    <View style={styles.text}>
                    {filtered.map((item) => {
                    return (
                        <p key={item.id}>
                            Nom: {item.titre} 
                           - Date: {item.date} 
                           - Rating: {item.note}/10
                        </p>
                    );
                      })}
                    </View>
```

image of the app :
[see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/spajc.png)

Answer (score 2):

You are using `!search` which returns `true` if `search` is `undefined`. However, your default `state` is set to the empty string `""`, which is not undefined, thus `!""` returns true.

Thus, `data` is always returned. You need to check the length of the `search` string and if it is equal to zero, return the filtered data.

```js
const filtered = search.length > 0
        ? data.filter((item) =>
            item.titre.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase())
         ) : []
```

Comment: It sounds like OP wants to show nothing by default therefore he could return empty array instead of data

Comment: @Hyetigran this is a good suggestion and actually better, thanks. I have changed it.

Answer (score 0):

Pass `null` to filtered if search is empty.

```js
const filtered = search.length === 0
    ? null
    : data.filter((item) =>
        item.titre.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase())
    );
```

and on your view, return fragment when `filtered` is null

```js
 <TextInput style={styles.search}
                    value={search} 
                    onChange={handleSearchChange}
                    ></TextInput>
                    <Text style={styles.text}>Résultat rapide :</Text>
                    <View style={styles.text}>
                    {!filtered ? <></> : filtered.map((item) => {
                    return (
                        <p key={item.id}>
                            Nom: {item.titre} 
                           - Date: {item.date} 
                           - Rating: {item.note}/10
                        </p>
                    );
                      })}
                    </View>
```